# Maintain consistency in concurrent read operations in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an API in Node.js say `/create/appointment` which does 2 operations

STEP 1: Check for active appointment in DB.

STEP 2: Create an appointment if not exist.

I have 3 collections

1. `doctors`
2. `patients`
3. `appointments`

appointments collection has 3 main fields

`doctor_id`: MongoDb ObjectID
`patient_id`: MongoDB ObjectID
`is_active`: Boolean

STEP 1 contains one DB read operation.
STEP 2 contains one DB write operation.
When the API is fired multiple times simultaneously,
STEP 1 of second cycle is executed before STEP 2 of first cycle completes. Since STEP 2 of first cycle is not completed, STEP 1 of second cycle does not return the active appointment entry created in first cycle.

> I cannot use compound unique index on:
>
> 1. `{doctor_id, patient_id}`, since `appointment` collection can contain historical data.
> 2. `{doctor_id, patient_id, is_active}`, then `appointment` collection can contain only one inactive entry.

Implementation:

```
// All functions below return promise object.
doctorManager
.getDoctor(doctor_id)
.then(doctor => {
  // throw error if doctor does not exist
  return patientManager.getPatient(patient_id);
})
.then(patient => {
  // throw error if patient does not exist
  return getActiveAppointment(doctor_id, patient_id)
})
.then(activeAppointment => {
  // throw error if active appointment exist
  return appointmentManager.createAppointment(doctor_id, patient_id)  
})
.then(() => {
  // return API response
})
.catch(error => {
  // handel error
});
```

Is there a way to lock `appointment` collection when any sort of operation is going on, or any other better solution.
I cannot shard my DB nor setup replication.

Comment: You can use async await which will make it more readable and you will achieve your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something it will look when you use async await functionality. Its not problem solution but just an example of handling your problem properly.

```
  doctor = await doctorManager.getDoctor(doctor_id);
  patient =  await patientManager.getPatient(patient_id);
  appointment  = await doAppointmentExists(doctor_id, patient_id);

  if(isEmpty(appointment)) {
     create appointment = await appointmentManager.createAppointment(doctor_id, patient_id)
  } else {
    throw new Error("Duplicate Appointment");
  }
```

Comment: Note that this code would only solve consecutive calls from the same client, by making the client wait for the creation to finish before checking; it will not solve simultaneous calls from 2 clients.

Comment: @Kaddath oh thank you. I did not know that. 
I think my problem is pretty common many of them would have faced it during s/w development.